# How to justify a label next to the input field?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8tYi.jpg)
As in, in this image, the labels are slightly above to the input text fields. I want them to justify.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  border-left: 3px solid grey;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  float: left;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:50px;" align="middle">
  <b>Registration Form</b>
  <form>
    <label for="uname">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br>
    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"><br>
    <label for="cpwd">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  /* Set a width that accommodates your longest label */
  text-align: right;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  /* Adjust the right margin to space out the label from the input */
}

input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  border-left: 3px solid grey;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Adjust the top and bottom margin as needed */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  /* Set a width that works for your layout */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="uname">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="pwd">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="cpwd">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
</div>
```

remove the `float: left;` style from both elements as it's not necessary when using `inline-block`. always Enclosing each `label` and `input` pair in a `div` helps to ensure that each pair is treated as a block and its a good practice

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap every label & input in a separate span tag or div tag and then in css give this span tag `display:flex` and `align-items:center;` to vertically center them

```css
span{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
input { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  border-left: 3px solid grey;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  float:left;
}
label { 
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<b>Registration Form</b>
<span>
   <label for="uname">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
</span>
<br>
<span>
   <label for="pwd">Password</label>
   <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
</span>
<br>
<span>
   <label for="cpwd">Confirm Password</label>
   <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use inline-block property for label, like this:

```css
div.register input { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  border-top: 3px solid grey; 
  border-left: 3px solid grey; 
  margin: 0px 4px; /* top margin removed */
  display: inline-block; 
} 

div.register label { 
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right; 
}
```

```html
<div class="register">
 <label for="uname">Username</label>

 <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br>

 <label for="pwd">Password</label>

 <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"><br>

 <label for="cpwd">Confirm Password</label>

 <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
</div>
```